# What type of functions is Fourier series good for approximating?

Tags: numerical-methods, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Me and my friend were playing around with Fourier series and we tried to approximate $e^x$ , see [demos graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/k3nknawfvm). In it, it seemed that even if more than hundred terms were taken the approximation was very poor compared to the Taylor expansion to first hundred terms.

Why exactly is Fourier series a poor approximation here? In what cases would Fourier series be better than Taylor to approximate functions?

Comment: Fourier series can only approximate periodic functions.

Comment: An alternative for non-periodic functions is the Fourier transform. However, since $e^x\not\in L^1(\mathbb R)$, the Fourier transform is not well-defined.

Comment: Is the function period the whole real line @Trebor?

Comment: @user619894 I just checked

Comment: What is $L^1( \mathbb{R})$

Comment: @Buraian Any Fourier series will be a sum of cosines and sines (or a sum of $\exp(-2\pi i n x)$-es), so it will automatically be periodic.

Comment: @Buraian See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space. It is the space of all functions from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$ that are absolutely integrable.

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch if it is not well defined, what is the series that I got?

Comment: @Buraian ok now. Indeed it is periodic, if you change $k$ from integers to say half integers, you will see that the period is longer. To approximate a non periodic function you need a Fourier integral, not a series.

Comment: What is half integers @user619894

Comment: There is a mistake in your formula, the first term should be negative $-\sinh(\pi)/\pi$ and not positive. If you fix this you will see that it fits very well on $(-\pi,\pi)$ except at the boundary points (due to Gibbs phenomenon: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_phenomenon).

Comment: ...and here is the plot with this fixed: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/qhz3yalggt

Comment: Using the correction above, you got something like the Fourier series of the periodic function equal to $e^x$ on some bounded interval.